# Deriving the Poisson Integral Formula from the Cauchy Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

If $f$ is analytic inside and on the unit circle $\gamma$, show that for $0<|z|<1$,
$$2\pi if(z)=\int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw-\int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{w-1/\bar{z}}dw$$
and then derive the Poisson Integral Formula:
$$f(re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-r^2}{1-2rcos(\theta-t)+r^2}f(e^{it})dt, \qquad 0<r<1.$$

I know the Cauchy Integral Formula is $f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{w-a}dw$ for $a$ inside $\gamma$, and I also know its counterpart for derivatives, which is $f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}}dw$ for $a$ inside $\gamma$.

The former looks promising in terms of deriving the first equation, if only I can find $a$ such that $\frac{f(w)}{w-a}=\frac{f(w)}{w-z}-\frac{f(w)}{w-1/\bar{z}}$. I think a key point is working out where $1/\bar{z}$ lies in relation to $z$ but I can't seem to visualise it, thanks to the function at $0$ being a singularity. Is the idea that the first fraction has a zero at $w=z$ and the second at $w=\frac{1}{\bar{z}}$?

Putting the two fractions over a common denominator gives:
$$\frac{f(w)(w-1/\bar{z})-f(w)(w-z)}{(w-z)(w-1/\bar{z})}=\frac{zf(w)-(f(w)/\bar{z})}{(w-z)(w-1/\bar{z})}=\frac{(z-1/\bar{z})}{w^2-w(z+1/\bar{z})+z/\bar{z}}f(w)$$
which does look a little like the final equation I am trying to find if I let $z=re^{i\theta}$.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Okay, letting the second fraction in the first equation become $\frac{\bar{z}f(w)}{w\bar{z}-1}$, I can get the second, however it is negative. I.e. I get
$$f(re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_0^{2 \pi}\frac{r^2-1}{2rcos(\theta-t)+r^2+1}f(e^{it})dt$$
is this okay?

I am still struggling with getting the first equation, however. Is it the case that whenever $z$ is in $\gamma$, then $1/\bar{z}$ wont be and vice versa? In which case, why do you subtract them from each other?

Comment: You should indeed let $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $w=e^{it}$. Also, there is a $r$ inside your cosine in your formula, that should probably be a $t$, right?

Comment: For future visitors: here's another MSE answer regarding this topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147720/relationship-between-cauchys-integral-formula-and-poisson-kernel

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If $0 < |z| < 1$, $z$ lies inside of $\gamma$ and $1/\bar{z}$ lies outside of $\gamma$. So

$$\int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{w - z}\, dw = 2\pi i f(z)$$

by Cauchy's integral formula and

$$\int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{w - 1/\bar{z}}\, dw = 0$$

by Cauchy's integral theorem. This yields your first equation above.

Now

\begin{align}2\pi i f(z) &=\int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{w - z} \, dw - \int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{w - 1/\bar{z}}\, dw\\ &= \int_\gamma \left(\frac{1}{w - z} - \frac{1}{w - 1/\bar{z}}\right)f(w)\, dw\\
&=\int_\gamma \frac{z - 1/\bar{z}}{w^2 - (z + 1/\bar{z})w + z/\bar{z}}f(w)\, dw\\
&= \int_\gamma \frac{|z|^2 - 1}{\bar{z}w - (|z|^2 + 1) + zw^{-1}}f(w)\frac{dw}{w}\\
&= \int_\gamma \frac{|z|^2 - 1}{\bar{z}w + z\bar{w} - (|z|^2 + 1)}f(w)\, \frac{dw}{w}\\
&= \int_\gamma \frac{1 - |z|^2}{1 - 2\operatorname{Re}(z\bar{w}) + |z|^2}f(w)\, \frac{dw}{w}.\tag{1}\\
\end{align}

Letting $z = re^{i\theta}$ and parametrizing $\gamma$ by $w = e^{it}$, $0 \le t \le 2\pi$, we write

\begin{align}
\int_\gamma \frac{1 - |z|^2}{1 - 2\operatorname{Re}(z\bar{w}) + |z|^2}f(w)\, \frac{dw}{w}&= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1 - r^2}{1 - 2r\cos(\theta - t) + r^2}f(e^{it}) i\, dt.\tag{2}
\end{align}

By $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$2\pi i f(re^{i\theta}) = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1 - r^2}{1 - 2r\cos(\theta - t) + r^2}f(e^{it}) i\, dt.$$

This is equivalent to

$$f(re^{i\theta}) = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1 - r^2}{1 - 2r\cos(\theta - t) + r^2}f(e^{it}) \, dt.$$ $$$$

Comment: can you remind me why $$\int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{w - 1/\bar{z}}\, dw = 0$$ by Cauchy's theorem? I know $f(z)$ is analytic in the domain containing the disk $|z|<1$, so for any closed contour in the domain, $$\int_\gamma f(w) dw = 0$$, by Cauchy's theorem. But will this still hold for the integrand $ \frac{f(w)}{w - 1/\bar{z}}\,$?

Comment: Hi @J.Kyei, since $\dfrac{1}{\bar{z}}$ lies outside $\gamma$, the denominator $w - \dfrac{1}{\bar{z}}$ cannot be zero. The quotient of two analytic functions with non-vanishing denominator is an analytic function.

Comment: Oh okay, Thank you  very much.

Comment: Why does $ \int_\gamma \frac{|z|^2 - 1}{\bar{z}w - (|z|^2 + 1) + zw^{-1}}f(w)\frac{dw}{w} = \int_\gamma \frac{|z|^2 - 1}{\bar{z}w + z\bar{w} - (|z|^2 + 1)}f(w)\, \frac{dw}{w} $? This seems to imply $w^{-1}=\bar{w}$.

Comment: Yes @A.B., on the unit circle $\gamma$, $w^{-1} = \bar{w}$ since $w\bar{w} = 1$ on $\gamma$.