# Holomorphic function with real values on boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

I am wondering if the next statement is true:

If $f:\Omega \rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be an holomorphic function where $\Omega$ is a bounded connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ such that for every $z\in \partial\Omega$ we have that $f(z)\in \mathbb{R}$ then f is constant and $f$ analytic and continuous on closure of $\Omega$.

I know that this is true if $\Omega$ is a symetric set because of schwarz reflection principle and Liouville theorem.

And the statement hold if $\Omega$ a disk of radius $R$ centered at a point $z_0$ because then composing $f$ with then function $g(z)=z-z_0$.

We would have have that $ f\circ g : D(0,R) \rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ so by the preceding argument we have $f\circ g$ is constant so is $f$.

The condition that $\Omega$ is bounded is important since there exist function being real on boundary of $\Omega$ but not constant. For exemple $Id:H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  where $H=\{z \mid \Im z \gt 0\}$

But I don't know if this is true in general cases and I didn't find counterexample so if someone can give me an answer it would be super great

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's unclear what you're saying is true because the second sentence doesn't include a proposition.

Comment: I think you mean that the assumption should imply that $f$ is constant?

Comment: Oh yes sorry I edit my post (I mean if f takes real value on bondary then f constant)

Answer (score 2):

The answer will depend on how regular do you want the function $f$ to be near $\delta\Omega$ and on topological properties of $\Omega$ that you are probably assuming, but not writing. For example:

The function $$g(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{\frac{z}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{zi}{2}-\frac{i}{2}},&z\neq 1\\0,&z=1\end{cases}$$ satisfies that for $|z|=1$

$$\overline{g(z)}=\frac{\frac{\overline{z}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}{-\frac{\overline{z}i}{2}+\frac{i}{2}}=\frac{\frac{1}{2z}+\frac{1}{2}}{-\frac{i}{2z}+\frac{i}{2}}=\frac{\frac{z}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{zi}{2}-\frac{i}{2}}=g(z)$$

Therefore, it takes real values on the unit circle. This function takes the unit disc to the upper half-plane. Therefore, it is essentially your own example of the identity on the upper half-plane, after the conformal transformation $g(z)$.

---

Should $f$ be continuous on $\overline{\Omega}$? In that case we have that $f=\overline{f}$ on $\delta\Omega$. Therefore $f-\overline{f}$ is harmonic, zero on the boundary, and continuous on $\Omega$. Therefore, by the maximum principle, it is zero in the interior of the domain. Hence $f=\overline{f}$, which implies that $f$ is locally constant.

---

There is also the connectivity of the set $\Omega$. If $\Omega$ is not connected, $f$ could be real and constant on each connected component, but not constant over all.

Comment: Yes of course I was assuming that $\Omega$ was a connected set

Comment: @SamiMir Well, who knows what are the assumptions if they are not written. What about how regular is $f$ near the boundary? By the way, it is better to start with the actual domain of the function and then say all properties it satisfies on certain subsets of it. If you say $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$, then maybe $f$ is not a function defined on $\delta\Omega$, and if it is, you need some relation between the values on $\Omega$ and the values on $\delta\Omega$.

Comment: I edited the post but yes sorry to missed some hypothesis or not being explicit

Answer (score 1):

You want to assume $f$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $\Omega$.  The $\text{Im}(f(z))$ is harmonic, and $0$ on $\partial \Omega$.  If it were not identically $0$, it would have a maximum or minimum in $\Omega$, and that is impossible.